# CSS Drop Down Menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple CSS drop down menu that when you mouse over a link, the sub menu appears. I've managed to achieve this when you mouse over an li but can't figure out how to do it using a link.

The reason why I'm trying to do this using a link rather than the li is that my menu width is 100% and the li spans a greater area than the link so if you mouse over that area, the sub menu appears when you don't want it to.

My CSS is as follows:

```
.menu {
    border: solid 1px red;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-family: 'Raleway', arial, serif;
}

.menu ul {
}

.menu ul.children {
    display: none;
}

.menu ul li {
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul.children {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

.menu ul li a {
    padding: 10px 10px 0 40px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: There are thousands of tutorials for any kind of dropdown, slide left do anything menus around the web and a quick search on SO would show you there are already solid solutions posted. You don't need to reinvent the wheel each time...

Comment: Try this http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/

Comment: "Son of Suckerfish" is another solid place to start: http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using JS for this if possible. It's not necessary. Just stick a div inside your li (with a bit less padding on it than the li itself) and style the `div:hover` to `display:block;`.

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spycho/gjqF2/) demonstrating the approach. It's much like what you already have.

Comment: when your mouse is out it disappears so now the menu is gone.can you show how to make it stay please.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, this is not something you can do in CSS as the nested `<ul>` is in the `<li>` and not the `<a>` (Or the entire submenu would be a link and that's just silly)

You can get around that with javascript/jquery

```
$('.menu ul li a').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().children('ul').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <script src="http://webdesign9.in/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
$.fn.menumaker = function(options) {  
 var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
   format: "dropdown",
   sticky: false
 }, options);
 return this.each(function() {
   $(this).find(".button").on('click', function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
     var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
     if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
       mainmenu.slideToggle().removeClass('open');
     }
     else {
       mainmenu.slideToggle().addClass('open');
       if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
         mainmenu.find('ul').show();
       }
     }
   });
   cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
multiTg = function() {
     cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
     cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
       if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
         $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').slideToggle();
       }
       else {
         $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').slideToggle();
       }
     });
   };
   if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
   else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
   if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');
resizeFix = function() {
  var mediasize = 900;
     if ($( window ).width() > mediasize) {
       cssmenu.find('ul').show();
     }
     if ($(window).width() <= mediasize) {
       cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
     }
   };
   resizeFix();
   return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);
 });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#cssmenu").menumaker({
   format: "multitoggle"
});
});
})(jQuery);
    </script>
   <title>WELCOME TO WEBDESIGN9.IN</title>
   <style>
   #cssmenu,#cssmenu ul,#cssmenu ul li,#cssmenu ul li a,#cssmenu #head-mobile{border:0;list-style:none;line-height:1;display:block;position:relative;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
#cssmenu:after,#cssmenu > ul:after{content:".";display:block;clear:both;visibility:hidden;line-height:0;height:0}
#cssmenu #head-mobile{display:none}
#cssmenu{font-family:sans-serif;background:#EEE;}
#cssmenu > ul > li{float:left}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a{padding:17px;font-size:12px;letter-spacing:1px;text-decoration:none;color:#ddd;font-weight:700;}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,#cssmenu ul li.active a{color:#fff}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover,#cssmenu ul li.active:hover,#cssmenu ul li.active,#cssmenu ul li.has-sub.active:hover{background:#448D00!important;-webkit-transition:background .3s ease;-ms-transition:background .3s ease;transition:background .3s ease;}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a{padding-right:30px}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after{position:absolute;top:22px;right:11px;width:8px;height:2px;display:block;background:#ddd;content:''}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before{position:absolute;top:19px;right:14px;display:block;width:2px;height:8px;background:#ddd;content:'';-webkit-transition:all .25s ease;-ms-transition:all .25s ease;transition:all .25s ease}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before{top:23px;height:0}
#cssmenu ul ul{position:absolute;left:-9999px}
#cssmenu ul ul li{height:0;-webkit-transition:all .25s ease;-ms-transition:all .25s ease;background:#333;transition:all .25s ease}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover{}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul{left:auto}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li{height:35px}
#cssmenu ul ul ul{margin-left:100%;top:0}
#cssmenu ul ul li a{border-bottom:1px solid rgba(150,150,150,0.15);padding:11px 15px;width:170px;font-size:12px;text-decoration:none;color:#ddd;font-weight:400;}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a{border-bottom:0}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover{color:#fff}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after{position:absolute;top:16px;right:11px;width:8px;height:2px;display:block;background:#ddd;content:''}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before{position:absolute;top:13px;right:14px;display:block;width:2px;height:8px;background:#ddd;content:'';-webkit-transition:all .25s ease;-ms-transition:all .25s ease;transition:all .25s ease}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before{top:17px;height:0}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover,#cssmenu ul li.has-sub ul li.has-sub ul li:hover{background:#363636;}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.active a{border-left:1px solid #333}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a,#cssmenu > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active> a{border-top:1px solid #333}

@media screen and (max-width:900px){
.logo{position:absolute;top:0;left: 0;width:100%;height:46px;text-align:center;padding:10px 0 0 0 ;float:none}
.logo2{display:none}
nav{width:100%;}
#cssmenu{width:100%}
#cssmenu ul{width:100%;display:none}
#cssmenu ul li{width:100%;border-top:1px solid #444}
#cssmenu ul li:hover{background:#363636;}
#cssmenu ul ul li,#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li{height:auto}
#cssmenu ul li a,#cssmenu ul ul li a{width:100%;border-bottom:0}
#cssmenu > ul > li{float:none}
#cssmenu ul ul li a{padding-left:25px}
#cssmenu ul ul li{background:#333!important;}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover{background:#363636!important}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a{padding-left:35px}
#cssmenu ul ul li a{color:#ddd;background:none}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a{color:#fff}
#cssmenu ul ul,#cssmenu ul ul ul{position:relative;left:0;width:100%;margin:0;text-align:left}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before{display:none}
#cssmenu #head-mobile{display:block;padding:23px;color:#ddd;font-size:12px;font-weight:700}
.button{width:55px;height:46px;position:absolute;right:0;top:0;cursor:pointer;z-index: 12399994;}
.button:after{position:absolute;top:22px;right:20px;display:block;height:4px;width:20px;border-top:2px solid #dddddd;border-bottom:2px solid #dddddd;content:''}
.button:before{-webkit-transition:all .3s ease;-ms-transition:all .3s ease;transition:all .3s ease;position:absolute;top:16px;right:20px;display:block;height:2px;width:20px;background:#ddd;content:''}
.button.menu-opened:after{-webkit-transition:all .3s ease;-ms-transition:all .3s ease;transition:all .3s ease;top:23px;border:0;height:2px;width:19px;background:#fff;-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);-moz-transform:rotate(45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(45deg);-o-transform:rotate(45deg);transform:rotate(45deg)}
.button.menu-opened:before{top:23px;background:#fff;width:19px;-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);-moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);-o-transform:rotate(-45deg);transform:rotate(-45deg)}
#cssmenu .submenu-button{position:absolute;z-index:99;right:0;top:0;display:block;border-left:1px solid #444;height:46px;width:46px;cursor:pointer}
#cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened{background:#262626}
#cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button{height:34px;width:34px}
#cssmenu .submenu-button:after{position:absolute;top:22px;right:19px;width:8px;height:2px;display:block;background:#ddd;content:''}
#cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after{top:15px;right:13px}
#cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after{background:#fff}
#cssmenu .submenu-button:before{position:absolute;top:19px;right:22px;display:block;width:2px;height:8px;background:#ddd;content:''}
#cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before{top:12px;right:16px}
#cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before{display:none}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.active a{border-left:none}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a,#cssmenu > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a{border-top:none}
}
   </style>
</head>
<body>

<header>
<nav id='cssmenu'>
<div class="logo"><a href="index.php">Responsive </a></div>
<div id="head-mobile"></div>
<div class="button"></div>
<ul>
<li class='active'><a href='#'>HOME</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>PRODUCTS</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>BIO</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>VIDEO</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>GALLERY</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: (1) While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so. (2) You should use your flags to mark this question as a duplicate some other question where you posted the exact same answer ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31183117), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31181845), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31181826), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31181774/1816580)). If this is not a duplicate then provide custom answers and don't simply copy them to multiple questions.