# html css drop down menu in navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I have the following navigation bar on website.

[image]

I have tried adding a sub nav to html as follows (you can see under subject and pricing tab > subnav 1 and 2)

here is the html of nav layout

```
<header>
     <nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h1><a href="index"><strong>Virtual-Tutor</strong>Center</a></h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index" class="current">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="language-tutoring">Subjects &amp; Pricing</a>
                          <ul>
                          <li><a href="subnav 1">subnav 1</a></li>
                          <li><a href="subnav 2">subnav 2</a></li>
                          </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="how-online-tutoring-works">How it Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="system-requirements">System Requirements</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>


                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </nav>
</header>
```

However i am having trouble fixing the css to match the look and feel of the original nav design, color and layout.

```
header h1 {background:url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat 0 0;padding:2px 0 0 38px;font-family:'ColaborateThinRegular';font-size:26px;line-height:1.2em;color:#fff;font-weight:normal;float:left}
header h1 a {color:#fff;text-decoration:none}
header h1 strong {font-family:'ColaborateBoldRegular';font-weight:normal}
header nav {padding:7px 0 10px 0}
header nav ul {float:right;padding:2px 0 0 0}
header nav ul li {float:left;padding-left:4px}
header nav ul li a {position:relative;float:left;font-size:14px;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;font-family:'ColaborateThinRegular';text-transform:uppercase;height:32px;line-height:32px;background-color:#181717;padding:0 36px 0 10px;border-radius:17px;-moz-border-radius:17px;-webkit-border-radius:17px}
header nav ul li a:hover, header nav ul li a.current {background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ee3c09, #b90a09);/* FF3.6 */background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #ee3c09),color-stop(1, #b90a09));/* Saf4+, Chrome */filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr= '#ee3c09', endColorstr= '#b90a09');/* IE6,IE7 */-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr= '#ee3c09', endColorstr= '#b90a09')";/* IE8 */}
header nav ul li a:after {content:'';display:block;position:absolute;right:12px;top:13px;width:4px;height:7px;background:url(../images/arrow1.gif) no-repeat 0 0}
header .adv-content {overflow:hidden;background:#f9f9f9;padding:10px 0 8px 0}
header .breadcrumbs {float:left;padding:3px 0 0 10px}
header .breadcrumbs li {display:inline;color:#212121;padding-left:5px}
```

I have gone through numerous sub navigation coding samples but can't figure out how to add a subnav with the same look and feel as the parent navigation bar. all examples show working from scratch on their own design. Can somebody please help with css?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Drop Down Menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506571/css-drop-down-menu)

Comment: Jon, all i need is some css help to get a matching look and feel as my parent nav.. all coding samples ive seen are working from scratch on their own design..

Answer (score 1):

this forum is for specific questions about  code you may be struggling with, not general questions about how to create an entire feature for your site.

If you look to the right side of this page you will find your question has been asked several times before. You can check out those questions and see how others have answered, or even better, here's a great and easy-to-follow tutorial for you to check out: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/

Comment: Dan, i ve looked trough numerous sub nav code samples, however all im trying to do is get a css which matches my original nav design and layout.. all samples show how to work from scratch on a navigation bar..