# How to add a drop down on hover to css menu

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [html css drop down menu in navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500631/html-css-drop-down-menu-in-navigation-bar)

I have an existing menu with categories displaying horizontally.  How can I make it drop down a vertical list of links when you hover over each category?  Like a traditional menu acts.

Here is what I have so far:  http://jsfiddle.net/chaddly/GrEWS/3/

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

​

```
#nav li a:hover 
{
   background-color:#333333;
   padding-bottom:12px;
   border-bottom:2px;
   border-bottom-color:#f37022;
   border-bottom-style:solid;
   margin:-1px;
}
#nav li a 
{   
   font-family:Arial;
   font-size:12px;
   text-decoration: none;
   float:left;
   padding:10px;
   background-color: #123261;
   color:#ffffff;
   border-bottom:1px;
   border-bottom-color:#000000;
   border-bottom-style:solid;
}
#nav li 
{
    display:inline;
}
#nav
{
    padding:0;
}
```

​Here is an example

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? You can take a look at the code here on dynamicDrive http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/jquery_multi_level_css_menu_2/ where they have made a multilevel dropdown menu...

Comment: Please show that you have at least tried some things. The issue at hand is as old as CSS (almost) and has been solved in many different ways. Google is your friend.

Comment: Can you include the "vertical list of links" in your question?

Comment: Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try the bootstrap dropdown menu..
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns